# Fetch data from table based on multiple columns from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of course :

[image]

I want to fetch data from searching based on columns Country, university, level, interest and substream.

Query which I've tried but not getting better result.

```
select *
from edu_college_desc
where (country = @country and
       university = @university and
       leveln = @level and
       interest = @interest and
       substream=@substream)
   or (country = @country or
       university = @university or
       leveln = @level or
       interest = @interest or
       substream = @substream)
```

What I want to do is: if select only country then the data should come based on only country or if I select only stream then data fetched based from stream only if I select both or more then data fetch should be based on those columns.

How can I get perfect results?

Comment: Use `ColName LIKE '%YourValue%` instead of `ColName = YourValue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this method,

```
select * from edu_college_desc 
where   country     =   ISNULL(@country ,country)
    and university  =   ISNULL(@university ,university)
    and leveln      =   ISNULL(@level ,leveln)
    and interest    =   ISNULL(@interest ,interest
    and substream   =   ISNULL(@substream,substream)
```

In this you can pass the value `NULL` to any of the parameters if it is not selected.(ie If you have set value only for @university and others are `NULL`, then result will be `university  = @university`)

Comment: abdul is that possible without using the value null i can get the result.

Comment: use default NULL while declaring this parameters, then no need to pass or assign this.

Comment: i tried but not getting results. In sql query is working perfectly but when i run this query into website and passing the parameters then i'm not getting result because the parameters are passing ' ' blank value not null.

Comment: what is the datatype of parameters ? try with Null-able Int datatype. Otherwise try to pass DBNULL instead of ' ' blank value.

Comment: i passed DBNULL also and other thing also but still it is passing blank value i'm using dropdownlist in asp.net c# from there i'm selecting value and i passed null value on first index of DDL.

Comment: i am not an expert in c#, but i think something similar to this,  Parameter.Value = (object)YourDDL.Index ?? DBNull.Value;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111001/discussion-between-abdul-rasheed-and-shashank).

Answer (score 2):

For each category, check if the parameter is null (not given) or the same as specified:

```
select *
from edu_college_desc
where (@country is null or country = @country)
  and (@university is null or university = @university)
  and etc...
```

And, of course, you can also use MS SQL Server's `ISNULL`, just as in Abdul Rasheed answer. Convenient but less portable.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be like :

`SELECT * FROM edu_college_desc
 WHERE
      (@country IS NULL OR country = @country) AND
      (@university IS NULL OR university = @university) AND
      (@level IS NULL OR level = @level ) AND
      (@interest IS NULL OR interest = @interest) AND
      (@substream IS NULL OR substream= @substream)`

Answer (score 0):

This code will definitely help you.

> `SELECT * FROM edu_college_desc
>   WHERE
>   (country = @country or isnull(@country,0)= 0)
>   AND
>   (university = @university or isnull(@university,0)= 0)
>   AND
>   (leveln = @leveln or isnull(@leveln,0)= 0)
>   AND
>   (interest = @interest or isnull(@interest,0)= 0) 
>   AND
>   (substream=@substream or isnull(@substream,0)= 0)`